# CSS3 Page Curl Shadows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give the footer of a webpage I'm designing a css3 page curl shadow effect. I've found guides online and I think I've mostly modified the code to my situation, but I'm still having some problems. When I set the before and after to position: absolute (like the guide does), it makes my footer's background/background color disappear.

Here's a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9ns7/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I just needed to add a defined width to the footer_container div. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to employ jQuery, there is a useful [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) for applying interesting corner effects on elements...I'm sure you could work on this to make it seem like a page turning.

Comment: I'm not against jQuery, I just don't know enough about it to modify any of those to look like shadows.